# how to use dictionary in creating XML file in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml, vb.net

I am creating an XML file in vb.net and using dictionary to create a node in the XML file for denoting country name but it throwing me an error.
and the code i used in dictionary is:

```
Dim countryNode As XmlNode = docm.CreateElement("country")
Dim cntry As String = dtreader("country").ToString().ToLower()
Dim cntryname As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
cntryname.Add("united states", "us")
cntryname.Add("united kingdom", "uk")
cntryname.Add("india", "in")
countryNode.AppendChild(docm,cntryname)
jobNode.AppendChild(countryNode)
```

And the error thrown is:

```
Too many arguments to 'Public Overridable Function AppendChild(new 
child As System.Xml.XmlNode) As System.Xml.XmlNode
```

How to resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar at all with this, but looking at your code it seems that you should do:

```
countryNode.AppendChild(cntryname)
```

instead of

```
countryNode.AppendChild(docm,cntryname)
```

Since `AppendChild` only accepts one argument.

Comment: I tried your code but it throws me an another error called 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of string,string) cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'

Comment: Like i said, i'm not familiar with this, but there are lots of answers about this subject. see if it can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bvb.net%5d%20dictionary%20to%20xml